# Send text message in jetpack compose and get callback

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, sms, android-jetpack

How to send a text message on button click and get a callback that a message is sent successfully in jetpack compose.

We have a code for Android in kotlin but need help regarding jetpack compose.

I have tried to see the Android code but did not get how to implement it in Jetpack compose.

The main question is like that:
I want to send a simple text message from the default message app on my phone and once the message is sent it should redirect back to my app.

Comment: where do you want to send the message? describe your problem clearly and provide the kotlin code

Comment: There's not much to do about this in jetpack compose, just use `Button` and in onClick call that kotlin code that you already have. If that's not possible for some reason, you have to explain better why it's not.

Comment: Provide more info, are you sending an API call to send message, or it is just a static method?

Comment: @zaidkhan I have edited the question let me know if it is not clear elaborate more if needed.

Comment: @HimanshuBansal I have edited the question let me know if it is not clear elaborate more if needed.

Comment: I believe the default SMS app for each phone brand is not implementing setResult when someone is sending a message with their app. One possible solution is to create your own sms app as somenone [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29821378/12030603)